# Trouble with if-statement using any( ) and apply( )

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

Suppose that I have the following table of information:

```
firstname <- c('Todd','Sven','Robert','Jovan','Angelo')
city <- c('Edmond', NA ,'Miami','Houston', NA)
state <- c('OK','KS', NA, 'TX', NA)
job <- c('Clown','Plumber','Professor', 'Uber Driver', 'Therapist')

list_test <- data.frame(firstname, city, state, job)
list_test

  firstname    city state         job
1      Todd  Edmond    OK       Clown
2      Sven    <NA>    KS     Plumber
3    Robert   Miami  <NA>   Professor
4     Jovan Houston    TX Uber Driver
5    Angelo    <NA>  <NA>   Therapist
```

I want to return a message if any of the columns is NA, which can be identified by doing this:

```
any(apply(list_test, 2, function(x){any(is.na(x))}))
[1] TRUE
```

My thought is to create a simple if-return statement like below.

```
if(any(apply(list_test, 2, function(x){any(is.na(x))}))) {
  return("At least one row has an NA value.")
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

I am confused as to why I am getting this error message.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you meant `print` or `stop` rather than `return`? Also, probably more idiomatic to do `any(sapply(list_test,function(x) { any(is.na(x)) }))`.

Comment: Your definition of "if any of the columns is NA" is basically the same as "are there any NA in the data.frame", in which case we can simply do `any(is.na(list_test))`. Your code returns an error because `return()` can only be placed within a function.

Comment: Thank you both. I tried 'stop' and 'warning' with success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlo's comment above is correct:

`return()` only works as part of a function, namely it returns the final value of the function. You don't have a function within your `if` statement, so you get the error message from `return()` itself.

Try running `return("foo bar")` interactively--you'll see the same error message.

As joran pointed out, use `print` to print to the console rather than return.

Comment: Yep, confirmed. Thanks!